# Button in fragment not working

Tags: android, button, fragment

I can get my button to work if I remove everything from my shared preferences down.  How can I get my button to work and keep my preferences?

I'm not sure if I'm posting my code right.  I rarely post anything.  If I did that wrong please let me know what I need to do to fix it.

```
public class FairgroveDirectory extends Fragment
{
    ImageButton fairgrove_cell;

    public FairgroveDirectory() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fairgrove_directory, container, false);
        fairgrove_cell = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fairgrove_cell);
        fairgrove_cell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked the button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        SharedPreferences fontSize =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        // Get the font size option.  We use "FONT_SIZE" as the key.
        // Make sure to use this key when you set the value in SharedPreferences.
        // We specify "Medium" as the default value, if it does not exist.
        String fontSizePref = fontSize.getString("FONT_SIZE", "Small");

        // Select the proper theme ID.
        // These will correspond to your theme names as defined in themes.xml.
        Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FontSizeSmall);
        if ("Medium".equals(fontSizePref)) {
            contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FontSizeMedium);
        }
        else if ("Large".equals(fontSizePref)) {
            contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FontSizeLarge);
        }
        else if ("XLarge".equals(fontSizePref)) {
            contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FontSizeXLarge);
        }
        // Set the theme for the activity.

        // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

        // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
        return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fairgrove_directory, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: return root; replace this with your code

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by:

```
return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fairgrove_directory, container, false);
```

line, because accessing Views from different object of `fairgrove_directory` and returning new View object from `onCreateView`.

Use same object `root` from which accessing View like `ImageVIew` to return as View from onCreateView:

```
return root;
```

Comment: @jamesburnison: There is no relation between both. so let me know what problem getting is returning `root` ?

Comment: [CODE]LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
[CODE\]

Comment: At that line I get "there is no access to variable localInflater"

Comment: @jamesburnison: remove `LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);` line then try or plz show your updated code

Comment: Now at this line [CODE]Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FontSizeSmall);[\CODE] I get "there is no access to variable ContextThemeWrapper"

Comment: @jamesburnison: ok move code from `SharedPreferences fontSize....` to `// Set the theme for the activity.` line before `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fairgrove_directory, container, false);` line and then use `LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);`

Comment: That puts me back at the problem where "there is no access to variable localInflater"

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fairgrove_directory, container, false);`
 with `return root;`

Answer (score 0):

replace " LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
        // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
        return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fairgrove_directory, container, false);"
 with return "root";